# How to use the poisson process for BLE neighbor discovery?

Tags: probability, poisson-process

I am trying to use the Poisson process for BLE(Blueetooth Low Energy) neighbor discovery. In this context, there are two devices called **Advertiser** and **Scanner**. The advertiser and scanner emit and listen to beacons in a duty-cycled fashion. This leads to longer discovery latency sometimes and I want to use the poisson process for the scanning and advertising patterns and prove the discovery is going to happen.
Basically I want to merge two poisson processes and make sure there are two events within a small interval delta.